# Wordpress add_action inside another function

Tags: wordpress

I want to add a style tag to the head section according to shortcode parameters. I wrote a function for styles and want to call its `add_action` in a shortcode function.

However, the style is not added in the head. If I call add_action outside of the function, it works successfully.
Please let me know how I can call the statement "add_action" inside a php function, and how I can send parameters to a function to call add_action.

This is my code:

```
function ag_appearance( $year ){
?>
<style type="text/css">
    /*Some style here*/
</style>
<?php
}

add_action( 'wp_head', 'ag_appearance' ); /*  this is working */

function dp_agenda( $atts, $content = null ){
   extract( shortcode_atts( array(
    'year' => '',
    'day' => '',
    'summit' => '',
    'complexity' => '',
    'certification' => '',
    'event' => '',
    'make' => ''
    ), $atts ) );
    add_action( 'wp_head', 'ag_appearance' ); 
  /*  this is not working, while i want to call here by $year parameter */
}
```

Comment: this has actually been asked before. you can find it here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/46167/add-action-in-a-function-is-it-possible

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a CSS file containing the style you want to add to the header (`appearance.css` for example) and placing that in the theme folder so you know where it is (I usually use `/css` for styles). Then use [wp_enqueue_style](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style) to set the style in the header when the containing function is called. Sort of like this:

```
function dp_agenda( $atts, $content = null ){
   extract( shortcode_atts( array(
    'year' => '',
    'day' => '',
    'summit' => '',
    'complexity' => '',
    'certification' => '',
    'event' => '',
    'make' => ''
    ), $atts ) );
    wp_enqueue_style('appearance',get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/css/appearance.css'); 
  /*  this is not working, while i want to call here by $year parameter */
}
```

Enqueued styles in WordPress, by default, are placed in the head via `wp_head()` and scripts are placed wherever you have `wp_footer()` placed, usually before the `</body>` tag.

You can also use [wp_enqueue_script](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) to pull your javascript files.

Comment: If you had bothered reading the question at all, you would know that your answer is 100% irrelevant.